# IOS 7 AFNetworking 2.0 view refresh issue

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, afnetworking

first I'd like to say that the issue I am having is in regards to how my own code is set, not IOS or AFNetworking.

I am going to show 1 example where a view is not refreshing immediately even though the updated JSON response object from the server is being recieved.

There are 2 views being used in the first view the button below takes the user to a second view where he can upload an image that will then be displayed in the first view.

```
- (IBAction)editImage:(id)sender {
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
TDUserProfileViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TDUserProfileImageEditViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Below is the code that uploads the new data to the server and then gets new data regarding the images's address on the server.

```
- (IBAction)dataSubmitToServer{


//    NSLog(@"photo: %@", self.photoData);
 NSString * userID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:USERID];
//make the call to the web API
NSString* command = @"setProfilePhoto";
self.params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:command, @"command", userID, @"userid", nil];

//////////////////
NSLog(@"%@", self.params);


self.photoName = @"newname.png";
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];



manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:BaseURLString parameters:self.params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.userPhoto.image, 1)
                                name:@"image"
                            fileName:self.photoName
                            mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

       } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    [TDPublicFunctions showDefaultAlert:@"Error" body:[error description]];
}];

[self getNewProfileData];


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


}

-(void)getNewProfileData{
/*start getting new data for profile pic and status message*/

NSString* command = @"displayProfileData";

NSString * userID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  objectForKey:USERID];

NSMutableDictionary* params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:command, @"command",  userID,@"userid", nil];

NSLog( @"%@", params);
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:BaseURLString parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    if([responseObject objectForKey:@"error"])
    {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Data Retrieval Error" message:[responseObject description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString * profilePhoto = [[[responseObject objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"profile_picture"];
        NSString * status = [[[responseObject objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"status"];
        NSString * statusMsg = [[[responseObject objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"status_message"];

        if(profilePhoto && ![profilePhoto isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:profilePhoto forKey:PROFILE_PHOTO];
        if(status && ![status isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:status forKey:STATUS];
        if(statusMsg && ![statusMsg isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:statusMsg forKey:STATUS_MESSAGE];

    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
//end of getting data for status message and profile pic
}
```

Now once this above process is over the HUD is supposed to stop and when the back button on the view is hit there should be a newly uploaded image in the first view. The code below is the last of many things that I have tried in order to get the view with the image to refresh:
    -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

```
NSString * profPic = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:PROFILE_PHOTO];
NSLog(@"profilepic: %@", profPic);
//    NSString* status = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:STATUS];
NSString * statusMsg = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:STATUS_MESSAGE];
if(profPic)
    [photo loadIconForProduct:profPic];

if(statusMsg)
    statusMsgView.text = statusMsg;

//self.view=nil;
//[self viewDidLoad];
[self getFriendsList];
[photo setNeedsDisplay];
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

After an image is uploaded it may work the first time an image is uploaded but it does not work if the user were to press the editImage button a second time and upload another image.

What is it that is being done wrong? Let me know if there is anything else that I can supply.

Thanks.

Comment: Just my two cents.. Add a random number at the end of the url like `...image.jpg?rand=6547` so that everytime the image url is considered as new one.

Comment: Tried this, still have to logout and log back in to see the new image. Is there anything at all that I am not doing that someone may suggest in order to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see here, you are getting a URL back as the result of the profilePhoto. So you might as well use the AFNetworking function:

Im presuming photo is a UIImageView.

```
[photo setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profPic] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"somePlaceholderImage"]];
```

Comment: ok so i got that, I could use AFNetworking to load up the image. I will try it,  but I have noticed that other dynamic data (basic label text) on the view is also not reloading. Is there anything that I am currently not doing that should be done in order to make sure that the data on the view reloads?

Comment: From the code above, this is what I understand, please correct me if I'm wrong: the user clicks on a UIButton, a view controller is pushed and some data is uploaded, what happens next?

Comment: 2 views are used. Button takes user from view 1 to view 2. In view 2 images is uploaded. User then hits the back button and is back to view 1, new image should display. In view 1 there is also a btn that takes the user to view 2 where a user enters text that is then uploaded to the servers. User then hits the back button and is taken back to view 1 where there should be a label with the text that was just uploaded. If I completely exit out of the app and go back into the view, the updated data displays correctly. I need the data to be updated by the time that the user hits the back button.

Comment: I think you're problem is not with the reloading of the data, its with the AFNetworking function that gets the image. As you may already know it is asynchronous. So my best guess is that when you load view1 (go back from view2) the data is still not retrieved, so view1 is reloaded with basically nothing. So that is why when you were testing it worked, as when you tried to show the data, it was already retrieved, but when the view loaded it wasn't.